# Passing a test with multiple attempts (conditional probability)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

You have two attempts available. Must pass once to pass overall. Probability of passing on the first attempt is $\mathbb{P}(P_1) = 0.7$, and the probability of passing (language used in the question; I assume this is passing 'overall') is $0.8$. So if I denote failing by $F$, this would mean $\mathbb{P}(P_1\cup P_2\cap F_1) = 0.8$. I'm assuming that if you pass the first time, you don't take the test again.

**Question**. Given an individual passes, what is the probability they only passed on the second try?

**My working**. Using the information provided, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(P_1\cup P_2\cap F_1) = \mathbb{P}(P_1) + \mathbb{P}(P_2\cap F_1) - \mathbb{P}(P_1\cap P_2\cap F_1).$$
Since you can't fail *and* pass the first attempt, that last term is $0$. Therefore,
$$\mathbb{P}(P_2\cap F_1) = \mathbb{P}(P_1\cup P_2\cap F_1) - \mathbb{P}(P_1) = 0.8-0.7 = 0.1.$$
Then
$$\mathbb{P}(P_2\cap F_1 | P) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(P_2\cap F_1\cap P)}{\mathbb{P}(P)} = \frac{0.1}{0.8} = 0.125.$$

I can't really see any other way to do this, but this seems way too simple; I feel like the 'trick' part here is that $\mathbb{P}(P_2\cap F_1\cap P)\neq \mathbb{P}(P_2\cap F_1)$, but I don't understand why not (note that I do not have an 'official answer' for this).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Practice question assigned in a university course or similar?

Comment: Do you mean $P(P_2\cap F_1)$ in the very last expression?

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad.

Comment: Note that, $P_2 \cap F_1 \cap P \subseteq P_2 \cap F_1$ also, $P_2 \cap F_1 \subseteq P$, so, $P_2\cap F_1\cap P = P_2 \cap F_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tricks at all here. $\mathbb P(P_2\cap F_1\cap P)$ *is* equal to $\mathbb P(P_2\cap F_1)$ because the event $P$ (passing at all) is a superset of $P_2\cap F_1$ (passing the second time); if you pass the second time you have passed, and that is that.